# Device Token incorrect with Urban Airship?

Tags: ios, xcode, push, urbanairship.com

I'm trying to implement push notifications in my app. So, for testing, I built up a new app and did all the necessary steps (I hope...). I added to my project the following:

```
-AirshipConfig.plist
-libUAirship-1.1.4.a
-UAGLobal.
-UAirship.h
-UAObservable.h
-UAPush.h
```

and all the frameworks listed on their website.

My AppDelegate.m is:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "UAirship.h"
#import "UAPush.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

-(void)setupPushWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


//URBAN AIRSHIP PUSH NOTIFICATION CONFIGURATION
//Init Airship launch options
NSMutableDictionary *airshipConfigOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
//[airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"5QQmJyTMRZWks0nbx-9pHQ" forKey:@"DEVELOPMENT_APP_KEY"];
//[airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"OMuzzHdCQOCnrOtfiWox9Q" 
forKey:@"DEVELOPMENT_APP_SECRET"];
[airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"xrUoy0B1RdyjZqZXEuwIsg" forKey:@"PRODUCTION_APP_KEY"];
[airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"qiRlUvoaSHGNeXxw9pj71w" forKey:@"PRODUCTION_APP_SECRET"];

#ifdef DEBUG
[airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"NO" forKey:@"APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD"];
#else
[airshipConfigOptions setValue:@"YES" forKey:@"APP_STORE_OR_AD_HOC_BUILD"];
#endif

NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];
[takeOffOptions setValue:airshipConfigOptions 
forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsAirshipConfigKey];    

// Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
// Please replace these with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
[UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];

[[UAPush shared] resetBadge];//zero badge on startup    
[[UAPush shared] 
registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability|UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert]; // register for Newsstand and Alerts

}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
//Init Airship launch options
NSMutableDictionary *takeOffOptions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[takeOffOptions setValue:launchOptions forKey:UAirshipTakeOffOptionsLaunchOptionsKey];

// Create Airship singleton that's used to talk to Urban Airship servers.
// Please populate AirshipConfig.plist with your info from http://go.urbanairship.com
[UAirship takeOff:takeOffOptions];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
 registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound |
                                     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[self setupPushWithOptions:launchOptions];
return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application  
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
UALOG(@"APN device token: %@", deviceToken);
 NSLog(@"%@", deviceToken);
// Updates the device token and registers the token with UA
[[UAirship shared] registerDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application  
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
NSLog(@"Failing in APNS registration: %@",error);
}

@end
```

In this way I get the Error Apple Push service rejected device token 
But I also figured out that my device token could be retrieved not correctly. Following a UA member staff suggestion I downloaded from the Appstore the App Wide Angle, and I launched it witht my iPhone connected and with the Xcode console open. So I can see that my device token is another one...Where could it be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't hardcode your variabels into Urban Airship like this.

> Create AirshipConfig.plist The library uses a .plist configuration
>   file named AirshipConfig.plist to manage your production and
>   development application profiles.
>
> Create 2 applications within your Urban Airship account - one for
>   development & another for production. Ex. Name_of_your_app_dev
>   Name_of_your_app_prod Create an AirshipConfig.plist file Set the
>   following values to the ones in your applications